# document.createElement('script')... adding two scripts with one callback

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I need to add prototype and then add scriptaculous and get a callback when they are both done loading. I am currently loading prototype like so:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js";
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = callback;
document.body.appendChild( script );
```

I could do this by chaining the callbacks, but that seems like poor practice ( I don't want a silly chain of 20 callback methods when I need to load more scripts). Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you add those script to a HTML insted of loading it with JavaScript?

Comment: I am making a bit of code to be pasted into other people's html to embed my stuff. I only want an empty div and a reference to my javascript file to be pasted in.

Comment: @kdiegert: this reference to your js file pasted in: you mean via `<script src="my.js"></script>`?

Comment: yep, so the code to be pasted in would be:
    <div id="myDiv"></div><script src="my.js?arguments=arguments"></script>

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/async-script-loader-with-callback/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I propose you to use some small loader which will chain and do stuff for you. For example like this one:

```
function loadScripts(array,callback){
    var loader = function(src,handler){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = null;
            handler();
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        (head || document.body).appendChild( script );
    };
    (function run(){
        if(array.length!=0){
            loader(array.shift(), run);
        }else{
            callback && callback();
        }
    })();
}
```

This script should help you to build the script tags and call your callback when all files are loaded. Invoke is pretty easy:

```
loadScripts([
   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js",
   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js"
],function(){
    alert('All things are loaded');
});
```

Hope this will help

Comment: aysnc.parallel or async.series might help with this  https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: `arguments.callee` throws an error in strict mode: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode "`arguments.callee` is no longer supported. In normal code `arguments.callee` refers to the enclosing function. This use case is weak: simply name the enclosing function! Moreover, `arguments.callee` substantially hinders optimizations like inlining functions, because it must be made possible to provide a reference to the un-inlined function if arguments.callee is accessed.

Comment: @GabrielLuethje, changed it to named function

Comment: Can you please verbosely document what you did there?

Comment: This solution was useful when using SinglePageApplication like Ember .

Answer (score 2):

Because of a bug in Internet Explorer the recursive loader program from nemisj is not working correct in IE. Can be solved by setting a delay on the recursive call like:

```
function loadScripts(array,callback){  
    var loader = function(src,handler){  
        var script = document.createElement("script");  
        script.src = src;  
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){  
          script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = null;  
          if(/MSIE ([6-9]+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent))window.setTimeout(function(){handler();},8,this);  
          else handler();  
        }  
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
        (head || document.body).appendChild( script );  
    };  
    (function(){  
        if(array.length!=0){  
                loader(array.shift(),arguments.callee);  
        }else{  
                callback && callback();  
        }  
    })();  
}
```

This small hack does it, and often is the solution in IE, when an unexplainable problem occurs, which is too often.

Answer (score 1):

Since scriptaculous requires prototype, you will have to chain the listeners, with whatever method you use to load these scripts.

There are various script loaders available to load scripts in parallel, as fast as possible, e.g. [LABjs](http://labjs.com), but none is going to help much in this scenario.

If you end up having 10-20 scripts to load, I would recommend combining the scripts beforehand, using a tool such as a [Combiner](http://github.com/nzakas/combiner).

Comment: actually, this scenario is *exactly* what LABjs was designed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can promisify the [script's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) `.onload` and `.onerror` callbacks, then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all of the promises to resolve before continuing with execution that is dependent on these scripts.

Here's an example:

```js
const loadScript = url => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = e => 
      reject(Error(`${url} failed to load`))
    ;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  })
;

const scriptURLs = [
  "https://unpkg.com/htm",
  "https://unpkg.com/axios@0.21.0/dist/axios.min.js",
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js",
  // ...
];

Promise.all(scriptURLs.map(loadScript))
  .then(async () => {
    /* Use your scripts here */
    console.log("proving scripts loaded:");
    axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    console.log(d3.csvParse("a,b\n3,4\n5,6"));
    const html = htm.bind((t, p, ...c) => ({t, p, c}));
    console.log(html`<h1 id=hello>Hello world!</h1>`);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```