# Can running JavaScript code load JSONP instead of a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, load, jsonp, head

I just got JSONP working with the help of answers to [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/79485). Now, in my setup, the HTML file loads JavaScript via the script tag:

```
<script src="js/playlistcontroller.js"></script>
```

Now my question is, can this code, while running, trigger loading my JSONP response?

The goal is to **avoid** having

```
<script src="playlistcontent.jsonp"></script>
```

in the HTML Head, but do that stuff in the controller (which happens to be an [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) controler, if you are curious).

**It this possible (Loading JavaScript from JavaScript)?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically add script tag with src that may include document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully-cross browser tested script:

```
var CFLoad = {
    fScript : null,
    isFileReady : function ( v ) {
        return ( ! v || v == "loaded" || v == "complete" || v == "uninitialized" );
    },
    js : function(src,cb,attrs) {
        var s = document.createElement( "script" ),
            done = !1, i;
        s.src = src;
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        for ( i in attrs ) {
            s.setAttribute( i, attrs[ i ] );
        }
        s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function () {
            if ( ! done && CFLoad.isFileReady( s.readyState ) ) {
                done = !0;
                if(cb) cb(s);
                s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
        };
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if( !done) {
                done = !0;
                if(cb) cb(s,1);
            }
        }, 5000);
        if(this.fScript===null) this.init();
        this.fScript.parentNode.insertBefore( s, this.fScript );
    },
    css : function(href,cb,attrs) {
        var l = document.createElement("link"),i;
        l.href = href;
        l.rel = "stylesheet";
        l.type = "text/css";
        for ( i in attrs ) {
            l.setAttribute( i, attrs[i]);
        }
        if(this.fScript===null) this.init();
        this.fScript.parentNode.insertBefore(l,this.fScript);
        if(cb) window.setTimeout(cb, 0);
    },
    init : function() {
        this.fScript = document.getElementsByTagName( "script" )[ 0 ];
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
CFLoad.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js", function (script_tag, failed) {
    if(!failed) {
        CFLoad.js("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js", function(s, f) {
            if(!f) {
                alert("Loaded");
                js13 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
                main();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

In your case:

```
CFLoad.js("playlistcontent.jsonp");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it out!

Comment: I now have found a similar script from here: http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2010/05/20/lightweight-jsonp-without-any-3rd-party-libraries/

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing, but is wrapped to look like only for JSON! Nice find