# load jquery in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load jquery in an external js file and use it. 
Am doing it in **test.js** the below given way

```
   var src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js';
   document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="'+src+'" onload="init()">     </sc'+'ript>');

 function  init(){
       $(function(){
         //jquery code here
  });
 }
```

Am getting $ reference error if do not call function **init()** onload.
  any other better method , then suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getScript` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.getScript( "external.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    init();
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined   

$.getScript( "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" )

guess you did not get my question properly. i want to use jquery in my external js. e.g in test.js

Comment: You want to use `getScript` from the jQuery library to load the jQuery library?

Comment: how we can use getScript without loading jquery file?? We need to load the jquery before we can use $ variable . So how to do that?

Comment: You can't use jquery to load jquery.  You won't have access to the `$` variable until jquery is included.  This question probably has an option you could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write

Comment: Read my question please. i know that i cant use jquery to load jquery. I have used javascript to do it , any other better method using javascript can you suggest ?

Comment: Do you have a URL to look at where this is happening?  I always put `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` in the HTML and any external scripts after it so they will all have access to jQuery

Comment: i dont want to use <script src="jquery.js"></script> in HTML file. 
but instead use var src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js';
   document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="'+src+'" onload="init()">     </sc'+'ript>');

in my js e.g test.js   which i will load in my HTML file

Comment: Sorry pal, not sure what else to do for you. Good luck