# How to add variable to src source in JS script?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
<script src="chat/script.php?room=1&username=John&draggable=1"></script>
```

and this does not:

```
<script>
var username="John";
</script>  
<script src="chat/script.php?room=1&username="+username+"&draggable=1"></script>
```

Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can do that using client-side code, but not using HTML:

```
<script>
var username="John";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "chat/script.php?room=1&username="+username+"&draggable=1";
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, your variable `username` is a JavaScript variable. Outside the `<script>` tag, HTML doesn't know about it. You would need to insert the `<script>` tag from within JavaScript. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write) describes how to do that.

In your case, it would be:

```
var my_script = document.createElement('script');
my_script.setAttribute('src','chat/script.php?room=1&username=' + username + '&draggable=1');
document.head.appendChild(my_script);
```

Answer (score 2):

The content of the script tag is executed, nothing in its attributes will be executed. You can dynamically add a script tag like so:

```
var username="John";
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "chat/script.php?room=1&username="+username+"&draggable=1";
documennt.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

This creates a new script element, sets the `src` property, and then inserts it into the HTML `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use a server-side language like PHP. That `src` attribute is not part of the Javascript. Only the code inside the `script` element.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `document.write` method as following:

```
var username = "John";
document.write( "<script src=\"chat/script.php?room=1&username=" + username 
                + "&draggable=1\"><" + "/script>" );
```

Note that i have break the `</script>` part such that it doesn't assumed as end closing tag of your main script block! the `\"`is used to escape the double quotation mark inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can change any element's `src` using this in your JavaScript:

```
let myElement = (document.getElementById("myElementHTMLId").src =
"some string" + myVariable + "some string");
```

Comment: Another option is to use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Example:
`myElement.setAttribute('src', 'srcValue');`

Comment: Not an answer, because they ask how to load a script with a dynamic url, not how to change url on an already loaded script