# Inside ng-show events are not triggering looks like an image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ajax

No java script events are triggering inside ng-show div in my code. Please find my code in the below plnkr link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/kGqk8x?p=preview

After loading the data from json i am making ng-show as true. But inside the div i have a button which is not allowing to do any of the js events. It looks like a image for me. Please help me to know where i am going wrong.

Here is my code

```
<body ng-controller="ArtSearch">
    <div ng-show="isShow">
        <table class="tbl_cls">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in names">
                <td>{{item.artistName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.trackName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.artworkUrl30}}</td>
                <td>{{item.shortDescription}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div align="center">
            <button value="asdf"></button>
            <a href="#" class="button">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="searchForArt">
        //some code
        <div align="center">
            <a href="#searchForArtist" class="button" ng-click="searchCall()">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/kGqk8x?p=preview
```

Comment: What function are you calling when the new content loads?

Comment: Loads some values from json file.

Comment: json won't work if you have JavaScript turned off TMK

Comment: I have resolved the ajax issue. Please help me to get answer for my question. My Question is not related to ajax/ loading the data from the json.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do is move the `$scope.isShow=true` inside of your promise like so:

```
$http.get("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack&limit=4")
    .then(function(response) {    
        $scope.names = response.data.results;
        $scope.isShow=true;
    });
```

But even this is not going to solve your problem. I'm pretty sure you'll never hit your `.then` because of how you wrote your http request. It will get blocked as a cross-origin request every time. If you want to see for yourself, open the browser console and try to click the search button. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452334/how-can-i-query-the-itunes-search-api-in-javascript) to see how to use jsonp to bypass this.