# Jquery: add script tag when screen size is less

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a script when the screen size is less than 900  but it doesn't add any script, but I get the alert message when screen size is less than 900. My question is different from this [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file). My problem is, the following script is not working in my system.

```
<script>

if($(window).width() <= 900) {
  alert("size is less than 900");
  var sc = document.createElement('script');
  sc.src = 'js-min/bootstrap/jquery.min.js';
  sc.type = 'text/javascript';
  if(typeof sc['async'] !== 'undefined') {
    sc.async = true;
  }  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/92dm07ss/ - inspect when loaded and you can see js file in head

Comment: It just displays the alert message but doesn't add the script tag inside the head tag

Comment: Have you looked at other SO answers? There's a very [similar one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write)

Comment: any error in the browser console....

Comment: @toomanyredirects yeah but it's not working in my case

Comment: It works in the fiddle so if not for you, then something else is breaking it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

For make that, try with `document.head.appendChild()` event.

```
if($(window).width() <= 900) {
  alert("size is less than 900");
  var sc = document.createElement("script");
  sc.src = "js-min/bootstrap/jquery.min.js";
  sc.type = 'text/javascript';
  if(typeof sc['async'] !== 'undefined') {
    sc.async = true;
  } 
  document.head.appendChild(sc);
}
```