# How to use a function in the src tag of an Javascript script

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML code and there somewhere I want to display a video with Javascript. I have a function that gives me a valid link to the video player and source. So if I post it directly without function in `src` it works fine.

So my question is how can I use my function in the `src` tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="get_link()"</script>
```

A solution without jQuery/document.* is wanted if possible. I know I could do something like that `document.getElementById("iframeid").setAttribute("src","link")`.

### Edit

All of the solutions were **not** working in my case. But anyways it's not a solution for me to do it in Javascript because of security issues. And there is no way to use nodejs. So thanks for your comments anyway. =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add script tag with src that may include document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write)

Comment: with the same method you need to generate the entire `script` tag.

Comment: "A solution without jQuery/**`document.*`** is wanted if possible." You'll have to explain why you have such an odd requirement. You need to manipulate the DOM _somehow_.

Comment: Please add additional details.  It sounds like you're trying to do something very strange.  Why can't you manipulate the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding script in JavaScript like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', get_link());
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I don't want to have the script in the head. =/

Comment: @kwoxer, If you are loading it asynchronously, How does matter where it is placed ?

Comment: @kwoxer then append to the body.

Comment: It just pastes document.write on my HTML page. Maybe I have some code affecting this? I gonna create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this attribute through JavaScript, you can't do so by directly putting it in the `src` attribute. You can attach some event handler on the HTML, such as `onclick="handler()"`, or something of that sort, which when triggered will give you access to the element within the function. Something like this.

```
function handler() {
    this.src= 'my_link.js
}
```

EDIT:

Not that the above solution is ideal, but just to meet the criteria of the question. It is possible, without any use of document to do this.

On your script tag, set an `onerror="change_link()"`. Then define an

```
function change_link() {
    this.src= get_link();
}
```

And last, you should add a faulty `src` attribute to the script tag. Again, this is stupid and you shouldn't do it in production code, but I'm just showing you that it's possible.

Comment: You mean? `<script type="text/javascript" onload="this.src=get_link();"></script>` That didn't work either.

Comment: That would be the cleanest way, however onload will not trigger unless the script tag already has something to actually load. AND once you set a new src for it the event will trigger again.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could write a complete example. Because I also tried `<script type="text/javascript">
          this.src=get_link();
        </script>`. This as well did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I'll edit my answer to show you a solution to match all your criteria, but you absolutely should not use it.