# Random generator within script tag

Tags: javascript

Hello I need help in assigning a random number to the src file in a script tag. I have read all the posts I could find, but not making any head way.

so here is what i am trying to do. In the code below, the file referenced by the src tag is myjsfile.1234.js.

What i want to is randomly generate the "1234" every time the page is loaded.

```
<script data-cfasync="false" id = "myid" src="https://www.example.com/myjsfile.1234.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
```

For example I have tried this without success

```
<script>
var randomnos = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000000);
var mysource = "https://www.example.com/myjsfile."+randomnos+".js";
</script>
<script data-cfasync="false" id = "myid" src=mysource  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So will appreciate any help I can get

Comment: You'll need to create the script tag programmatically and add it to the page. See, for example this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element

Answer (score 2):

Another way: using Jquery you can use $.getScript()

```
var randomnos = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000000);
var mysource = "https://www.example.com/myjsfile."+randomnos+".js";

window.onload = function() {
   $.getScript(mysource,function(){console.log('loaded')})
}
```

Comment: Will this technique execute the script after it is loaded?

Comment: Yes, Also you can call any code/function you want to execute in place of console.log(). the callback

Comment: for using jQuery + 1 ;-)

Comment: @EhisAsibor: Please test and mark this correct if it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to create script element programatically and append it to html page:

```
var randomnos = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000000);
var mysource = "https://www.example.com/myjsfile."+randomnos+".js";

window.onload = function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = mysource;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: If i do it this way, the called script is not executed... it just changes the tag and stops there. Obviously I want the contents of the new src file to be executed

Comment: @EhisAsibor works for me. Try to do it with some known script, not with random one