# can javascript be put in head tag to change the src attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have learnt to change the src attribute of an image using java script in body tag. Can I do the same using java script in head tag? If yes then how?

Comment: You need to show us your code...

Comment: You can but it won't be loaded. You should take a look at this to add dynamically a script in head : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write to add it with JS

Comment: Try to ask questions, when you think its solution isnt available on stackoverflow. Alway search before asking. Also, try to be more specific, always explain your approach and the problems you got in code. Otherwise, ye will get downvotes. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

see the snippet

```html
<head>
  <script>
  function changeSrc() {
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    console.log(image.src);
    image.src = "secondImagesrc";
    console.log(document.getElementById('image').src);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="imagesrc" id="image"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeSrc();">click me</button>
</body>
```