# how to call javascript via if else statement (I prefer use if else)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

how to call javascript via if else statement

```
if (localStorage.getItem('lang')=='zh'){
    //run  javascript prepared for Chinese (not a function but whole javascript file)
}
else {
    //run another javascript file prepared for English
}
```

Comment: Take a look at dynamically including scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add script tag with src that may include document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write)

Comment: If this is node or a [web module](https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7), you can use `require('./abc/xyz.js')`