# how i can put <script> in double quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the `script` tag using JavaScript. I'm putting the tag into double quote.
My problem is something else but solves with this simple example:

```
<script>
  document.write("<script>" + example_var + "<\/script>");
</script>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Then put it in single quotes...

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically add script tags in your DOM with javascript? The javascript inside that script tag won't be executed anymore.. See a similar question with answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write

Comment: *My problem is something else but solves with this simple example* – this sounds unclear, your example either doesn't work or solves the problem, please explain better. But, I believe you are having the problem that Laurens has mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two ways
**Template Literals**

```
document.write(`"<script>"${example_var}"<\/script>"`);
```

**Single Quotes**

```
document.write('"<script>"' + example_var + '"<\/script>"');
```

Comment: or even a third way: `"\"<script>\"" + example_var + "\"<\/script>\""`