# Can you get Heroku to use different code depending on mobile/web?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, heroku

Is there a way to deploy some code for the web (React) and deploy another different piece of code (Vue) for mobile? Just curious. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create `script` tag with `src` set to correct app bundle (either `react`, either `vue`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const appScript = document.createElement('script');
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // Mobile, put path to vue.js app bundle
    appScript.setAttribute('src','path/to/vue/app/bundle');
  } else {
    // Desktop, put path to react.js app bundle
    appScript.setAttribute('src','path/to/react/app/bundle');
  }
  document.head.appendChild(appScript);
</script>
```

Note: this answer is combined from those two:

[Create script on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write)

[Detecet a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)