# How to solve HTMX Partial Page Load issue caused by parallel script download?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, htmx, partial-page-refresh

By default the browser downloads and executes the script as soon as it reaches it in html file(unless `defer` or `async` attributes are used to force parallel download), So if you include a JS Library and then write the script dependent on the JS Library everything works fine.

However I've noticed that it's not the case with a partial pages. If it contains a library and script dependent on it, then before the library is downloaded and executed, the remaining scripts are called which create a problem as they were dependent on library.

In my example I use **[HTMX](https://htmx.org/)** *partial page load* to load HTML content which includes `Plotly.js` library and after it, html code and JS script required to create a chart. E.g.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div>
    <div id="f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:256px; width:100%;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {}; if (document.getElementById("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5")) {Plotly.newPlot("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5",[{"labels":["Newly Discovered","Indexed"],"values":[2,1],"type":"pie"}],{"template":{"data":{"histogram2dcontour":[{"type":"histogram2dcontour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"choropleth":[{"type":"choropleth","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"histogram2d":[{"type":"histogram2d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmap":[{"type":"heatmap","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmapgl":[{"type":"heatmapgl","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"contourcarpet":[{"type":"contourcarpet","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"contour":[{"type":"contour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"surface":[{"type":"surface","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"mesh3d":[{"type":"mesh3d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"parcoords":[{"type":"parcoords","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolargl":[{"type":"scatterpolargl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"scattergeo":[{"type":"scattergeo","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolar":[{"type":"scatterpolar","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"scattergl":[{"type":"scattergl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatter3d":[{"type":"scatter3d","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattermapbox":[{"type":"scattermapbox","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterternary":[{"type":"scatterternary","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattercarpet":[{"type":"scattercarpet","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}],"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}]},"layout":{"autotypenumbers":"strict","colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"hovermode":"closest","hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"ternary":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]]},"xaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","subunitcolor":"white","showland":true,"showlakes":true,"lakecolor":"white"},"title":{"x":0.05},"mapbox":{"style":"light"}}},"margin":{"t":25,"b":0},"height":256},{"displaylogo": false, "responsive": true})};
    </script>
</div>
```

When I refresh the page it loads perfectly as JS Library is downloaded and executed before chart's html and script. however in partial page load, before JS library is downloaded and executed, each plot's JS script is called which raises the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

So, How can serial load be enforced in partial pages?

or alternatively is there a better way to include JS libraries for specific pages to avoid this issue?

Comment: Could you try to wrap the chart creating JS inside a [`htmx.onLoad()` method](https://htmx.org/api/#onLoad)?

Comment: That won't work unless I write an event to call each script that that requires a library. even then by the time event is called, scripts are called before library is loaded.

Comment: [htmx:beforeRequest](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:beforeRequest) event can be used to load libraries before a partial page load. but it's not an elegant solution as it's both hard to implement in large projects and it's slow as the page-load will be done after libraries are downloaded which is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the Plotly lib inside each plots' JS script? Something like this should work:

```html
<script type="module">
  import 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js';
  window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {}; if (document.getElementById("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5")) {Plotly.newPlot("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5",[{"labels":["Newly Discovered","Indexed"],"values":[2,1],"type":"pie"}],{"template":{"data":{"histogram2dcontour":[{"type":"histogram2dcontour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"choropleth":[{"type":"choropleth","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"histogram2d":[{"type":"histogram2d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmap":[{"type":"heatmap","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmapgl":[{"type":"heatmapgl","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"contourcarpet":[{"type":"contourcarpet","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"contour":[{"type":"contour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"surface":[{"type":"surface","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"mesh3d":[{"type":"mesh3d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"parcoords":[{"type":"parcoords","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolargl":[{"type":"scatterpolargl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"scattergeo":[{"type":"scattergeo","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolar":[{"type":"scatterpolar","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"scattergl":[{"type":"scattergl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatter3d":[{"type":"scatter3d","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattermapbox":[{"type":"scattermapbox","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterternary":[{"type":"scatterternary","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattercarpet":[{"type":"scattercarpet","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}],"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}]},"layout":{"autotypenumbers":"strict","colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"hovermode":"closest","hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"ternary":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]]},"xaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","subunitcolor":"white","showland":true,"showlakes":true,"lakecolor":"white"},"title":{"x":0.05},"mapbox":{"style":"light"}}},"margin":{"t":25,"b":0},"height":256},{"displaylogo": false, "responsive": true})};
</script>
```

Note that your script must be of `type="module"`. Alternatively you can use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import):

```html
<script>
  import('https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js').then(() => {
    window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {}; if (document.getElementById("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5")) {Plotly.newPlot("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5",[{"labels":["Newly Discovered","Indexed"],"values":[2,1],"type":"pie"}],{"template":{"data":{"histogram2dcontour":[{"type":"histogram2dcontour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"choropleth":[{"type":"choropleth","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"histogram2d":[{"type":"histogram2d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmap":[{"type":"heatmap","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmapgl":[{"type":"heatmapgl","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"contourcarpet":[{"type":"contourcarpet","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"contour":[{"type":"contour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"surface":[{"type":"surface","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"mesh3d":[{"type":"mesh3d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"parcoords":[{"type":"parcoords","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolargl":[{"type":"scatterpolargl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"scattergeo":[{"type":"scattergeo","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolar":[{"type":"scatterpolar","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"scattergl":[{"type":"scattergl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatter3d":[{"type":"scatter3d","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattermapbox":[{"type":"scattermapbox","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterternary":[{"type":"scatterternary","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattercarpet":[{"type":"scattercarpet","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}],"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}]},"layout":{"autotypenumbers":"strict","colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"hovermode":"closest","hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"ternary":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]]},"xaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","subunitcolor":"white","showland":true,"showlakes":true,"lakecolor":"white"},"title":{"x":0.05},"mapbox":{"style":"light"}}},"margin":{"t":25,"b":0},"height":256},{"displaylogo": false, "responsive": true})};
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not load dependencies on each refresh. But in case it is necessary you need to insert your scripts dynamically and on their load event proceed with the rest of the code. Benefit also will be that the dependency can be loaded just once into the head of the main page.

```
function addScript( src, callback ) {
  var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
  s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
  s.onload=callback;
  document.body.appendChild( s );
}
```

In the callback you can initialize plotly so together it would look like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:256px; width:100%;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addScript( src, callback ) {
        var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
        s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
        s.onload=callback;
        document.body.appendChild( s );
    }
    function initPlotly () {
        window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {}; if (document.getElementById("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5")) {Plotly.newPlot("f657405b-14c4-4ca1-aef4-88d5842739f5",[{"labels":["Newly Discovered","Indexed"],"values":[2,1],"type":"pie"}],{"template":{"data":{"histogram2dcontour":[{"type":"histogram2dcontour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"choropleth":[{"type":"choropleth","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"histogram2d":[{"type":"histogram2d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmap":[{"type":"heatmap","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmapgl":[{"type":"heatmapgl","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"contourcarpet":[{"type":"contourcarpet","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"contour":[{"type":"contour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"surface":[{"type":"surface","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"mesh3d":[{"type":"mesh3d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"parcoords":[{"type":"parcoords","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolargl":[{"type":"scatterpolargl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"scattergeo":[{"type":"scattergeo","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolar":[{"type":"scatterpolar","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"scattergl":[{"type":"scattergl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatter3d":[{"type":"scatter3d","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattermapbox":[{"type":"scattermapbox","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterternary":[{"type":"scatterternary","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattercarpet":[{"type":"scattercarpet","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}],"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}]},"layout":{"autotypenumbers":"strict","colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"hovermode":"closest","hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"ternary":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]]},"xaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","subunitcolor":"white","showland":true,"showlakes":true,"lakecolor":"white"},"title":{"x":0.05},"mapbox":{"style":"light"}}},"margin":{"t":25,"b":0},"height":256},{"displaylogo": false, "responsive": true})};
    }
    addScript("https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js", initPlotly);
</script>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69616316/5173936 for dynamic script loading