# Include a JS file based on value in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using response.sendFile("mypage.html") in node js to send a page to the client. Now I have to add additional features based on certain conditions.

Here is what I have:

```
response.sendFile(page, options);
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
if (isEditor) {
    var myjavascripturl = "editor.js";
    response.sendFile(page, options, myjavascripturl);
}
else {
    response.sendFile(page, options);
}
```

But from what I've read I don't think it's possible to insert dynamic data into a sendFile call.

So I think this alternative approach might work also. That is to request a javascript file on the HTML but through a nodejs express rout:

I would have on my html page a script tag:

```
<script src="/editor"></script>
```

That calls my route and that points to this:

```
app.get("/editor", getEditorJS);

export async function getEditorJS(request: Request, response: Response, next: any) {

    if (isEditor) {
        response.sendFile("editor.js");
    }
    else {
        response.sendFile("nothing.js");
    }
}
```

as the inventor of this technic i call it the gigawatt call

The question is, is it possible to get or include a javascript file from express js as described and is there any reason to do this or not do this approach.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: _"from what I've read"_... you read correctly. Why not [render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) an EJS file (or whatever template format you're comfortable with)?

Comment: This sounds like an opinion-based question. Yes, you could do it the way you've described. Did you try it? Any reasons to do so or not would be pretty subjective. Browser caching would of course be a potential problem

Comment: The real question is, what determines the state of `isEditor`? If that state is driven from the client-side, why not let the client-side code make the decision to [dynamically include](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13121948/283366) the appropriate `<script>` tag?

Comment: @Phil re EJS: I did use it and I liked it until I had to figure out external assets like css and javascript. I had issues with getting the correct paths.  EJS pages were in one folder and public was in another. I suppose if I can put the ejs pages in the public folder that might solve some issues but there might have been an issue with that. The other probably non issue was if render behaves any different than sendfile? I think another issue was getting vscode html features when the file extension is .ejs.

Comment: @Phil isEditor is a server side variable and so I could use sendfile("normal_page") and sendfile("editor_page") but they'd be identical except for the javascript file.

Comment: @Phil I solved this by making a route that returns true or false for this value and then dynamically adds the script to the page.

Comment: step 1: don't use `sendFile()`, use a template engine with the `.render()` function so that you can pass templating values based on "whether those should be there or not". And then make different routes for different URLs of course. There is literally nothing stopping your express server from having a route for your index.html, and a route for your editor.js

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a route that returns true or false for this value. When the page loads I call this route and if support is enabled I dynamically add the script to the page as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write).

```
var isEditor = await getIsEditor();
if (isEditor) {
  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/editor.js");
  document.head.appendChild(js);
}
```