# Include javascript file in jsp from anothe javascript file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is it possible to include a javascript files in jsp dynamiacalyy, ie. in any listener or anything like that from the current javascript file. This is for speeding up the page load.

Comment: For a pure JS solution, you could use the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866717/document-createelementscript-adding-two-scripts-with-one-callback#1867135

Comment: thanks. it worked. if you post it as an answer, i will accept it :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple options, for example jQuery has $.getScript method. Or you can use http://requirejs.org/