# How to include a .js file in onclick button?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to make a button that will run a JavaScript when it was clicked.First, my script was like this

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert('Invalid username or password. Please try again.')
    }
</script>

<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Generate" href="submit.php" >
```

It works, and a popup appear.But when I try to call JavaScript from another site, nothing happens.

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {            
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://raw2.github.com/BlackEagleBCC/Script/master/myscript.js';
    }
</script>

<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Generate" href="submit.php" >
```

Comment: Did you run the code on web server

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the js file once event occurs.

Please refer to this [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml), it demonstrates dynamic including js and css.

Add html code

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('myscript.js','js')">Load "myscript.js"</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('mystyle.css','css')">Load "mystyle.css"</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then js code

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

Code for myscript.js

```
var petname="Spotty"
alert("Pet Name: " + petname)
```

Code for mystyle.css

```
#ul li{
background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Similar to this :

You can call loadjscssfile('myscript.js','js') inside your button onclick() event handler.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you copied over the part of the demo that directly addresses the question, rather than just a link...

Comment: Script Kiddies, you may also go through the provided link for live demo, also let me know if you are comfortable to implement your scenario :)

Comment: @ScriptKiddies, have you implemented it?

Comment: @Mazzu , nope. I don't know how to do it. :(

Comment: @ScriptKiddies, follow the steps as 1. Create your script file say for eg. myscript.js (as shown above). 2. Write loadjscssfile function code (as shown above). 3. Then in your button's function click that is myFunction() (as specified in your question), make function call as loadjscssfile('myscript.js','js'); 4. The output will be alert, as given in myscript.js file.

Comment: @Mazzu , sure, but how can i contact you personally? :)

Comment: @ScriptKiddies, mail me at shaikhmazahar@gmail.com

Comment: @ScriptKiddies, you can share me code at above mail id :)

Comment: @Mazzu , sure :) soon. sorry i'm a little bit busy

Comment: @ScriptKiddies, No probs, take your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Try this out:

```
<a id='myScript'  type="submit"  href="submit.php" > Generate </a>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myScript = document.getElementById('myScript');

    myScript.onclick = function(){

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://raw2.github.com/BlackEagleBCC/Script/master/myscript.js"; 
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**EDITED**: The below solution might not be what you are looking for now.

I have been using this,a solution which I found from stackoverflow itself.

```
function loadScripts(array,callback){
    var loader = function(src,handler){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = null;
            handler();
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        (head || document.body).appendChild( script );
    };
    (function(){
        if(array.length!=0){
            loader(array.shift(),arguments.callee);
        }else{
            callback && callback();
        }
    })();
}
```

This will help you create script tags.

```
loadScripts([
   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js",
   "https://raw2.github.com/BlackEagleBCC/Script/master/myscript.js"
],function(){
    alert('Scripts have been loaded successfully');
});
```

**Edited:**
I have used this method when I needed to build script tags and get a callback after everything loads fine. (These things come handy :) )
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867135/3222041

Comment: If you copy paste a code block from an other thread, even a long time ago, can you edit your post and indicating thread where you found it please ?

Comment: @franchez Sorry.. a little late.. Yes of course..I have added it along with the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @ScriptKiddies I have added the link I referred..Hope it helps you.

Comment: @newTag thanks a lot. but i still can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @ScriptKiddies I have provided a simple solution than the previous one.(previous solution which I think will not be needing for you now unless you have multiple scripts to load).