# requirejs-like module system for a legacy Javascript codebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, document-ready

I'm on a project that uses many Javascript files containing some jQuery code and a $(document).ready() call in the end. The script tags are included in the page from the server-side code if a feature is needed.

What would be the best way to gradually move to a requirejs-like module system (what I basically need is the declaration of dependencies on the .js file).

How people injected scripts on the page before AMD and CommonJS modules?

Comment: Maybe something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866717/document-createelementscript-adding-two-scripts-with-one-callback