# Can you append inline script tags below external scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an inline piece of javascript like this:

```
<html>
  <body
    <script>test1</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is an external js that is executed that appends a script below the inline script and over writes it, any thoughts on how to do that?

```
<html>
  <body
    <script>test1</script>
    <script>externaltest1</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.createElement('script')... adding two scripts with one callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866717/document-createelementscript-adding-two-scripts-with-one-callback)

Comment: u can use jQuery.getScript() if ur allowed to use jquery

Comment: Your title and your code are conflicting. It also doesn't matter if one is inline and the other is external.

Answer (score -1):

Confused on the question exactly, do you want to append a script tag into your html?

You can append script tags into your html with the following:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#yourElement").append(script);
```

Note: If you are looking to add external js, you would typically include these between `<head>` or in your footer like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="yourExtenalScriptPath.js"></script>`

Comment: I think OP said INLINE

Comment: @Byzod, the first example does append a script into the HTML, does it not?

Comment: Further, any function calls defined in both files would always be executed from the last script available, exactly what OP asked. I kindly ask you to reconsider your down vote.